# Image preview feature like Google and Lightbox + Iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, lightbox

How could I implement an image preview feature like Google image search result, when clicked on a thumbnail, Google shows a preview of website on the background and preview of the image on the foreground.

Is that possible to use Lightbox/Fancybox (or a clone of them) and iframe options? Do you have any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: I want to show content of another page in this box and an image as foreground, ex: http://www.google.com/imgres?tbnid=kPx4DAW9zSohZM:&imgrefurl=http://userlogos.org/node/4924&docid=agRsH34bP-1G7M&imgurl=http://userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow2.png&w=300&h=225&ei=E016T-_aKI_EtAbOtJj6AQ

Comment: what would happend when you close the lightbox? stays on the page or re-directs to the page where the image is located?

Comment: In google, when the image window is closed the page is re-directed to the page where the image is located.

Comment: but in your app you may need to input manually the url of both the image and the page (because you are not developing another search engine google-style, are you?) and display the image in a lightbox-style app. Is that correct?

Comment: in my app I have the url of both the image and the page. I Want to show an image which belongs to that page. In this manner Google evades copyrights of images so I want to use it also to show some photos which belong to other websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making this type of lightbox is easy. You don't necessarily need to use Lightbox/Fancybox. 
there are actually many examples of this online that you could use for a model...for instance I just found this one
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/

what I generally do for this type of pop-up-like thing is make a div with the following properties:

```
position:fixed;
top:left;
height:100%;
z-index:(something high);
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
display:none;
```

this will cover the page with a semi-transparent layer, or curtain
what I generally do to display the curtain is attach a function that sets "display:none" to "display:block" ( or alternatively, uses jquery's .toggle() ) to a click event somewhere on the page.

make sure that the contents of the pop-up are also initialized as display:none; in the css

I would then put the image inside the div, and position it with position: absolute;

I used this type of curtain/pop-up here on this page...http://asdf.us/imgrid/greatgrids
click "select, then click here for details"

**EDIT** : after reading your comment, I realize that this is more about using iframes WITH lightboxes. I would be careful using iframes, because some sites (like stackoverflow.com, for example) disallow iframe linking. Try this example below:

```
<html><head><style>
iframe, #curtain{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#curtain{
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
z-index:10;
text-align:center;
}
#theimg{
padding:20px;
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow"></iframe>
<div id="curtain">
  <img id="theimg" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/220px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png"></img>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: with this code, I have problem with images which have more height than  my screen size and without position:fixed; it doesn't show images correctly.

Comment: To display an image that is LARGER than the window size, without adding a scroller, you MUST add a max-width, max-height, width, or height property to the css that will make the image display at an appropriate size on your page. This is always true, lightbox or no lightbox.

The reason why you must use either position fixed, absolute or relative is that with position:static (the default value for the css position property) you cannot use z-index.